# Spatial partitioning of direct, indirect and total impacts

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to reproduce table 2.1 (p. 41) of LeSage and Pace (2009) by means of the **open R software**.

This is a table containing the direct, indirect and total impacts of a SAR model (since the regression coefficients cannot be interpreted directly because of spillovers), **partitioned by W-order**.

I am able to produce the first part of the table ( impacts() in R ), but for the moment I don't have a clue on **how to split these impacts per power of W in the R software**.

Please, could somebody give me a hint on how to do this? I would be very grateful!

Thank you very much in advance,

Janka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question is to set the Q-argument within the impacts-function.

Setting Q to X gives X splits for the first X powers.

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Spatial-partitioning-of-direct-indirect-and-total-impacts-2-td7586879.html